# JSON.parse() output changes if assigned to a variable

Tags: json, typescript, parsing, es6-map

I am developing a website where tickets for events can be bought. After selecting a ticket it is in the shopping cart. I have a sessionService.ts which basically is a `Map<string, any>` that reads/writes from/to the local storage. Storing the map as a JSON string works perfectly but when I load the data from the storage and try to parse the JSON string to the Map the data is not consistent anymore.

`console.log(JSON.parse(data))` shows the correct values but `let x = JSON.parse(data); console.log(x);` shows manipulated data.

I tried recreating the problem on Stackblitz but I was unable to do that.

```js
export class Ticket {
  public id: number;
  public created: Date;

  constructor(
    public reservation: boolean,
    public price: number,
    public section: number,
    public row: number,
    public seat: number,
    public event: number | Event) {
  }
}

private testParsing(){
    const custom = '[["Tickets",[{"reservation":true,"price":10,"section":null,"row":10,"seat":10,"event":5,"id":1,"created":"2019-06-14T14:16:17.144Z"}]]]';
    console.log('String to parse: ', custom);
    console.log('String parsed directly to console: ', JSON.parse(custom));
}
```

`console.log('String to parse: ', custom);` will display the correct values.

`console.log('String parsed directly to console: ', JSON.parse(custom));` here the output is worng id = 0, row = null, seat = null.

Logs from code: [image: https://imgur.com/a/BumYqkI]

What causes this problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: In your reported code there's not the `console.log` that is causing problems in your screenshoot

Comment: If you can't reproduce the problem in stackblitz then something is different and you should isolate that difference.  Since your code here doesn't constitute a [mcve] there's nothing people can do but guess.  My guess: you are not aware that [`console.log` on an object value might show you a "live" version of the object and not the state of the object as it was when you logged it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log#Logging_objects)

Comment: Please add a [mcve] that shows the actual problem, because this works exactly as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/9zft31jq/

Comment: custom is not format Json, can you try this :
```custom = '{"Tickets":{"reservation":true,"price":10,"section":null,"row":10,"seat":10,"event":5,"id":1,"created":"2019-06-14T14:16:17.144Z"}}';
```

Comment: I tried the two variations on JavaScript, and both worked, I think this a problem with angular.

Comment: `console.log(x)` does not have to stringify `x` right away.  If that is causing you trouble, do `console.log(String(x))`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that it is a nested structure, try using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(custom))` should get the same result. I was able to reproduce your problem and solve with this method in my console.

Answer (score -2):

It is because of value reference, of x to be manipulated in future makes json.parse work incorectly. Try creating reference variable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).